# Windows Server 2022 MSMQ issue

Tags: msmq, windows-server, windows-server-2022

In the local network i am pushing private msmq message from windows server 2012 to 2022. But the queue message is not getting populated in the 2022 server. But in the trace, i can see the message reaching the server.

Tried by giving all the permissions to the queue in 2022 server.

Comment: Enable MSMQ journalling, Dead Letter Queue, etc. 
Looks like the destination is discarding the message for some reason.

Comment: Tried by enabling journaling. It did not work.

Comment: The recommendation was so you could see the underlying cause from the Dead Letter Queue message. It wouldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed by adding a registry entry PermitAnonEveryoneSend in the path Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\security. Restarted the server and created the queue again. This worked for me.

Comment: When you answer your own question, you should mark it as the accepted answer. It'll show up in StackOverflow search results.